# Temporarily switch Java version in bash script- Ubuntu Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, java

I'm using the Java keytool as part of a larger bash script. I need to pass in a password to create a keystore, so used the command `keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass:file ${somefile}`.

This `-deststorepass:file` is only available in Java 7, according to the docs
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html

I've had the script working before, but I think on this machine the default Java must be Java 6, and I'm not sure I can be confident the `update-alternatives -config java` can be considered stable.

Does anyone please know of a way to set the Java version for a particular script for a linux environment? I saw this but I couldn't translate it myself to Linux.
[Switching between Java 7 and 8 in OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/650310/switching-between-java-7-and-8-in-os-x)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess your wish is not to temporarily change the system-wide default Java virtual machine, which could have unexpected side effects for other applications, but simply to find a machine that is suitable for your purpose.

Assuming your JVMs are installed in directories without spaces (an easy assumption in standard distros):

```
# wantedArg is the argument that we need 
function getSuitableAlternative() {
  cmd=$1
  wantedArg=$2
  JVM_LIST=$(update-alternatives --list $cmd) 

  # Try all available JVMs until we find one supporting the specified parameter
  for jvm in $JVM_LIST 
  do
    $jvm -help |grep -q -- -$wantedArg && { echo $jvm; break; }
  done
}

# Find a "java" command supporting "deststorepass" argument
suitableJvm=$(getSuitableAlternative java deststorepass)

# Bad luck. 
if [ "$suitableJvm" == "" ]
then 
  echo "No suitable JVM machine found" >&2
  echo "Please sudo apt-get install jdk7..." >&2
  exit 1 
fi

$suitableJvm <...>
```